# How to copy the data from one Workbook and paste the value only in another Workbook and allow macro to run only one time?

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste

When I accidentally run VBA code to copy/paste data from one Workbook to the target Workbook multiple times, it will create multiple rows with same data in the target Worksheet.
[image]

I want the VBA code to recognize the previous line is the same, to prevent data duplication.

Further, my VBA code will copy the formulas to my destination Excel file.
I want to copy the value only instead of the formula. I'm not sure how to use `PasteSpecial` in my VBA code.

```vb
Sub Copy_Paste_Below_Last_Cell()
    
    Dim wsDest As Worksheet
    Dim lDestLastRow As Long
    
    Set wsDest = Workbooks("Destination.xlsx").Worksheets("DataBase")
    lDestLastRow = wsDest.Cells(wsDest.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
    
    ' How to use PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues here?
    Sheet4.Range("B6:F6").Copy wsDest.Range("C" & lDestLastRow)
    
End Sub
```

### Edit:

```vb
Sub Copy_Paste_Below_Last_Cell1()
    
    Dim wsDest As Worksheet
    Dim lDestLastRow As Long
    
    Set wsDest = Workbooks("Destination.xlsx").Worksheets("DataBase")
    lDestLastRow = wsDest.Cells(wsDest.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
    
    If sheetWithVariable.CellWithVariable.Value = False Then
        Sheet4.Range("B6:F6").Copy
        wsDest.Range("C" & lDestLastRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        sheetWithVariable.CellWithVariable.Value = True
    End If
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Task:** copy from main workbook and paste in target workbook
without duplicating data.

This should do it. Adjust the config section of the code before trying  it.

```
Sub TransferData()

Dim main_wb As Workbook, target_wb As Workbook, main_sheet As String
Dim r As String, target_sheet As String, first_col As Byte, col_n As Byte
Dim next_row As Long, duplicates As Byte, pasted As Byte, last_col As Long

'CONFIG HERE
'------------------------
Set main_wb = ThisWorkbook
main_sheet = "Sheet1"
r = "B6:F6" 'range to copy in the main Workbook

'target workbook path
Set target_wb = _
Workbooks.Open("/Users/user/Desktop/target workbook.xlsm")

target_sheet = "Sheet1"
first_col = 3 'in what column does the data starts in target sheet?
'-------------------------

'turn screen updating off
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'copy from main
main_wb.Sheets(main_sheet).Range(r).Copy

With target_wb.Sheets(target_sheet)

    'target info
    next_row = _
    .Cells(Rows.Count, first_col).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    
    'paste in target
    .Cells(next_row, first_col).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    
    last_col = _
    .Cells(next_row, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

End With

pasted = last_col - (first_col - 1)

For col_n = first_col To last_col

    With target_wb.Sheets(target_sheet)

        If .Cells(next_row, col_n) = .Cells(next_row - 1, col_n) Then
             
             duplicates = duplicates + 1
             
        End If

    End With

Next col_n

If duplicates = pasted Then 'if the nº of cells pasted equals duplicates
    
    For col_n = first_col To last_col  'erase pasted range
        target_wb.Sheets(target_sheet).Cells(next_row, col_n).Clear
    Next col_n
    
End If

'turn screen updating back on
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution, but I'm relatively new to VBA, I'm not sure how to combine this with my code with your code although I can roughly understand your code. Seems like the code only check whether it is the same value as the line above and return True/False?

Comment: You understood it correctly. Okay, I'll modify your code.

Comment: Thank you Gassz! This solution work perfectly for me!

Comment: I'm glad it did ;)

Answer (score 0):

Go "Developer Tab" then press "Record macro" or at Excel bottom left side there is small button "Record macro". Then you press it it will create automatically code for every your click, press and etc., so go copy and paste only values, stop recording macro. And you will have Module1 with code how to "paste values".

Answer (score 0):

For `PasteSpecial` function, copying and pasting are defined as different operations (so as to say, no `Destination` option should be used for `Copy`):

```
Sheet4.Range("B6:F6").Copy
wsDest.Range("C" & lDestLastRow).PasteSpecial _ 
  Paste:=xlPasteValues
```

If you want your to code to run once, add a variable somewhere in your workbook that will specify that the code already run. Something like that:

```
Sub Copy_Paste_Below_Last_Cell()
  If sheetWithVariable.CellWithVariable.Value = False Then
    ' Put your code here
    sheetWithVariable.CellWithVariable.Value = True
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi ENIAC, thanks for your solution! When I run the second solution given by you, there is an error mentioned that the variable is not define. May I know what is the reason? I edited my post with my latest code attached, thanks!

Comment: @weizer, instead of `sheetWithVariable.CellWithVariable.Value`, you should use the name of sheet and a cell address where you will store your variable. Something like this:
`Sheet1.Range("A1").Value` or `Worksheets("Sheet 1").Range("A1").Value`

Comment: Updated my comment in the code. Put your code inside `If` block.